# Can a kerberos principal use a hostname/instance not matching the realm?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

Let say our realm is `CARS.LOCAL` and I can't change it.

Would a principal like `HTTP/portal.houses.com@CARS.LOCAL` works?

In other words, our internet domain name doesn't match our realm and I would like to use our registered domain name with kerberos.

The server hosting `portal.houses.com` and acting as a kerberos client to auth users is `server1.cars.local`. Reverse dns lookup works for `server1.cars.local`.

But `portal.houses.com` resolves to an ip not matching `server1.cars.local` in a reverse dns lookup.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Would the only way be to have an A record for `portal.houses.com` using a static ip and make that ip ptr record point to `portal.houses.com`?

I'm using Active Directory as the kerberos server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse DNS doesn't apply here.

Browsers will canonicalize CNames to A records and use the A record as the requested SPN. If `portal.houses.com` is a CName that *the client* resolves to `server1.cars.local`, then the browser will request a ticket to `http/server1.cars.local` from the domain controller associated to the logged on user.

The actual realm name doesn't matter. Kerberos is happy as long as there's an SPN registered on a service account.